# Parameters not valid when saving an image on C#

Tags: c#, .net

I can not save an image after adding watermark text on it
Here is one of my photo [One of my photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV3Wt.jpg)
I've gone through many solutions but it keeps throwing this error
[Parameters not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50p5L.png)
Here is my code

```
public static System.Drawing.Image AddWatermarkImage(string filename)
    {
        string text = "SỞ LAO ĐỘNG THƯƠNG BINH HẢI DƯƠNG";
        System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold);

        using ( System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename) )
        using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image) )
        {
            g.TranslateTransform(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2);
            g.RotateTransform(45);
            SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(text, font);
            g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Red, -( textSize.Width / 2 ), -( textSize.Height / 2 ));

            return image;
        }


    }
    public static void WaterMarkImage(string folderPath)
    {
        bool exists = Directory.Exists(folderPath);
        if ( exists )
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles(); 

            if ( Files.Length > 0 )
                foreach ( var img in Files )
                {
                    using ( System.Drawing.Image imgOut = AddWatermarkImage(img.FullName) )
                    {
                        imgOut.Save(img.FullName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }

                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: @mjwills it is full path of the image, eg: "D:\\Images\\MyImage.jpg"

Comment: I'm using .net framework 4.6.1, use can use any photo to test

Comment: You dispose an image, and then returns it from the method. Remove the first `using` statement in the `AddWatermarkImage` method.

Comment: I've posted one of my photo on the post. I remove 'using ( System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename) )' , it throws error "
A generic error occurred in GDI+"

Comment: In the `AddWatermarkImage` function, replace the first `using` with: `var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename)));`, keep the rest and try.

Answer (score 0):

Remove using the form below statement

```
using ( System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename) )
```

As pointed out by Alexander, the image object gets disposed of as soon as it goes out of scope after this statement.

Comment: I remove “ using...  “. Then it throws the error “ a generic error occurred in gdi+ “

Comment: This must be because 'img.FullName' is being used and you are trying to change it. Try saving it with a different path or with a name change.